# Shin Megami Tensei IV Neutral Route Questions

Tags: smt4

I am aiming for the neutral route in Shin Megami Tensei IV and a general guide says that by picking the first option for every question, it would lead to neutral. What about questions during battles? Would they also affect my aliment path?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672441-shin-megami-tensei-iv/66811622) is the best neutral path guide I've found for SMT IV.  It suggests that your choices in battle don't affect your alignment; they only affect the course of the battle/whether the boss gains or loses attack/defense power etc.

The only exception is where you get a moral choice, such as when you have the option to "execute" a boss at his request.  This happens a couple of times in the game, and I believe choosing to finish off the boss gets you chaos points, while choosing to spare him gets you law points.